# Can I split the output from a wireless adapter to feed two computers

Tags: wireless-networking

What I would like to do is to use a male-input-to-two-female-outputs USB splitter, connect the input to my wireless adapter, and connect each female output to a different computer. Would this work?

The two computers, both running Windows 10, are side by side in a room where the signal is very weak and the adapter needs a long (>10 metres) cable to my main computer. The other is a basic laptop whose inbuilt wireless card is not the most sensitive: that usually reports no signal, but sometimes shows just the dot.

Obviously a second adapter would do the trick, but to run the connecting cable would require drilling through two nine-inch walls as was done for the first connection. The existing holes are not large enough to pass a second cable.

Comment: After you've connected your main computer to the wireless adapter, you can then run an ethernet cable between the two computers and setup share internet on your main computer.

Answer (score 0):

No. USB signals cannot be split this way and USB devices do not support being shared between two devices.

There are USB switch type devices, whereby the USB device is effectively disconnected from one device and reconnected to the other, but only one device can be the "host" at a time. For example [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Sharing-Keyboard-Scanner-Printer/dp/B01N6GD9JO) will swap a group of USB devices between two computers or [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plugable-One-Button-Sharing-Between-Computers/dp/B006Z0Q2SI) to swap a single device (your wireless card) between two computers.

There is no way to "share" a single device so it can be used simultaneously though.

Answer (score 0):

No.  This will not work.  Two computers cannot share a single USB device, nor can they share a a network interface.  There are exceptions, but that is not relevant here.

There are viable alternative ways to have remote connectivity though:

1. Get a more powerful wireless access point
2. Use a [high gain antenna](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/high-gain-antenna-router/)
3. [Powerline ethernet](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/high-gain-antenna-router/)

Personally, I am a fan of powerline networking and use it at home.  Its fast, reliable, expandable, and very easy to set up.